# Whats the error in it. string assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, char

I would like to take the data from the struct elements to the internal elements.
What will be a better way to do it.
It shows error: invalid array assignmen berror: invalid array ssignment
error: invalid array assignment error: ‘strcpy’ was not declared in this scope.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    char Ip[16];
    char port[6];
    char sessionkey[32];
}


int main()
{

    char m_ip[16];
    char m_port[6];
    char m_sessionkey[32];

    A a;

    a.Ip = "10.43.160.94111";
    a.port = "12345";
    a.sessionkey = "12Abcd12345Abcd12345Abcd1234512";


    strcpy(m_ip,a.Ip);
    strcpy(m_port,a.port);
    strcpy(m_sessionkey,a.sessionkey);

    cout << "m_ip:" << m_ip << endl;
    cout << "m_port:" << m_port << endl;
    cout << "m_sessionkey:" << m_sessionkey << endl;
}
```

Comment: Horrible mix of c and c++. To use `strcpy()` please `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: funny you mention c++ and c++11 but your code doesn't use std::string at all.

Comment: #include <string> will work.

Comment: Don't use char[] or char* unless required. Prefer std::string which will handle copy, resizing, etc, without headache.

Comment: I have to use them. char[]. this is a requirement.

Comment: Oh... so this is homework then.

Comment: The error message tells you precisely what the problem is. You are trying to assign to arrays. You can't do that.

Comment: What C++11 teacher would require beginning programmers to use `char []`? Are you sure this isn't just a C course?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid inb4 the tag was suggested by SO.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid the use of `cout` and `operator<<` suggest that it is definitely intended to be C++ code.

Comment: Thanks All. got it correctly finally. the way I wanted. Was in a little hurry. Thought could use some suggestions fast.

Comment: @Hiesenberg Why did you chenge your original code? This only confuses readers of the thread. Now there is inconsistence between your question and the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean the following (C string functions are declared in header `<cstring>`)

```
    #include <cstring>

    //...

    char m_ip[16];
    char m_port[6];
    char m_sessionkey[32];

    A a = { "10.43.160.94111", "12345", "12Abcd12345Abcd12345Abcd1234512" };

    std::strcpy(m_ip,a.Ip);
    std::strcpy(m_port,a.port);
    std::strcpy(m_sessionkey,a.sessionkey);
```

Or instead of

```
    A a = { "10.43.160.94111", "12345", "12Abcd12345Abcd12345Abcd1234512" };
```

you could write

```
    A a;
    a = { "10.43.160.94111", "12345", "12Abcd12345Abcd12345Abcd1234512" };
```

provided that your compiler supports C++ 2011.

Take into account that you forgot to place a semicol after the closing brace in the structure definition

```
struct A
{
    //...
};
^^^
```

**EDIT:** After you unexpectedly changed your code I'd like to point out that this code snippet

```
    A a;

    string p = "10.43.160.94111";
    string q = "12345";
    string r = "12Abcd12345Abcd12345Abcd1234512";

    p.copy(a.Ip,16,0);
    q.copy(a.port,6,0);
    r.copy(a.sessionkey,32,0);
```

does not make sense. There is no sense to introduce objects of type `std::string` only that to initialize an object of type `struct A`.

Another thing you could initially define the structure the following way

```
struct A
{
        std::string Ip;
        std::string port;
        std::string sessionkey;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For writing in C++ prefer to use `std::string` instead of `char *` or `char[]`.
A number of your issues will not longer exist if you use `std::string` instead.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A
{
        std::string Ip;
        std::string port;
        std::string sessionkey;
};

int main()
{

        std::string m_ip;
        std::string m_port;
        std::string m_sessionkey;

        A a;

        a.Ip = "10.43.160.94111";
        a.port = "12345";
        a.sessionkey = "12Abcd12345Abcd12345Abcd1234512";

        // copy data from a to local variables
        m_ip = a.Ip;
        m_port = a.port;
        m_sessionkey = a.sessionkey;

        std::cout << "m_ip:" << m_ip << std::endl;
        std::cout << "m_port:" << m_port << std::endl;
        std::cout << "m_sessionkey:" << m_sessionkey << std::endl;    
}
```

If you insist on using `strcpy` you must include the C header file string.h either by using `#include <string.h>` or by using `#include <cstring>`. Note that this is a C header file and it is distinctly different than the C++ `#include <string>` header file.

Comment: Can `cstring` be included within C? I thought that `cstring` was only includable within C++ - and that it was the C++-friendly version of `string.h`. But I guess I never had any evidence for that!

Comment: no, `cstring` is the C++ way of including the C file `string.h` you cannot use `#include <cstring>` in C. I expect there may be C++ code added to `cstring` to add things such as `extern C` around the code which again is C++ specific for compiling C code with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
        char* Ip;
        char* port;
        char* sessionkey;
};


int main()
{

        char m_ip[16];
        char m_port[6];
        char m_sessionkey[32];

        A a;

        a.Ip = "10.43.160.94111";
        a.port = "12345";
        a.sessionkey = "12Abcd12345Abcd12345Abcd1234512";


        strcpy(m_ip,a.Ip);
        strcpy(m_port,a.port);
        strcpy(m_sessionkey,a.sessionkey);

        cout << "m_ip:" << m_ip << endl;
        cout << "m_port:" << m_port << endl;
        cout << "m_sessionkey:" << m_sessionkey << endl;
}
```

`strcpy()` function is in `cstring` header file in C++/C++11, so you must add `#include<cstring>` to your code.